# Stackdump Error working with Linked Lists

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am working on a homework assignment about linked lists. One of the functions I need to write is to add a node to the back of the linked list. The code I wrote in an attempt to do this is as follows:

```
void add_back(struct Node **list, int value)
{
  /* Variable Declarations                                                 */
  struct Node *pNewNode; /* A pointer to the new node we want to add       */
  struct Node *pTemp;    /* A temp pointer for walking through the list    */

  /* Allocate space for our new node and initialize its member variables   */
  pNewNode = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
  pNewNode->number = value;
  pNewNode->next = NULL;

  /* Sets pTemp to the head pointer, so we don't mess with it              */
  pTemp = *list;

  /* While we're not at the end of the list                                */
  while(pTemp->next != NULL)
  {
    /* Go to the next entry in the list                                    */
    pTemp = pTemp->next;
  }

  /* Have the previous end of the list point at the new end of the list    */
  pTemp->next = pNewNode;
```

}

The specific error message I'm getting is "0 [main] list 3384 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to list.exe.stackdump"

I tried looking at the stackdump file to try and gain some insight, but I'm not sure how to interpret it.

**Edit:** Here are pastebins to two other functions that could possibly be causing the error.

1. http://pastebin.com/8Y1kKqj2
2. http://pastebin.com/8RPUy1Jv

**Edit2** Here is a pastebin to my teacher's main function that is calling my functions

http://pastebin.com/1WibLgaY

Comment: Looks fine to me. Is there anything else in your program that you're doing that could be causing this?

Comment: I have no control over the main function and it should be correct because it was provided by my teacher and some of my fellow classmates have finished the lab. I added the other functions that could possibly be leading to this error in my main post.

Comment: In your `add_front()` method, you need to save the value `*list` is pointing to before you set `pNewNode` as the new head of the list.

Comment: Also, inside `free_node()`, the condition should be `while (pTemp != NULL)`. Otherwise you will be leaving one node left in the list.

Comment: Is setting the new node's next to list's value not saving it?

Comment: Right. My mistake :)

Comment: If this didn't help, is there any more code that could be causing the problem?

Comment: I don't think so b/c my teacher's main only calls these functions. But I will link the test function in his main, that might help.

Comment: the returned value from malloc needs to be tested to assure the operation was successful before using it. otherwise the following code is dereferencing from address 0

Comment: this code assumes that the *list is an actual instance of a struct Node, when it (I just checked and this is the case) only be a 'struct Node *' set initially to NULL.  If so, then the code needs to take that possibility into account.

Comment: your function is called 'add_back()' however, it is not called anywhere in the pastbin code.  there is a call to 'add_front()'.  This leaves me a bit confused as to what could be causing any 'stack smash' error from your code.  Perhaps it would help if you were to post the complete error message with back trace

Comment: Oh,I'm sorry. I was getting a similar error with my test_size funcion